# prove that if $f(x)+xf'(x)>0$ then $f(x)>0$

Tags: real-analysis

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: prove that ($f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$)

if $f(x)+xf'(x)>0$ then $f(x)>0$

Comment: $$f(x)+xf'(x)=\frac{d\left(xf(x)\right)}{dx}$$

Comment: more hint Please!

Comment: Are you assuming this holds on an interval or on *all* of $\Bbb R$? It would help you in thinking about the problem (and in using the hints) to know exactly what your hypotheses are and whether you're using them.

Comment: The intuition behind this problem is clearly that if we have a minimum, then by Fermat's rule, if $x_0$ is the minimizer, then $f(x_0) = f(x_0) + x_0 f'(x_0) > 0$, so $f$ must be strictly positive everywhere. For some reason I can't find any proof that $f(x) + x f'(x) > 0$ implies the existence of a minimum... any ideas people? I believe this is interesting.

Answer (score 10):

hint this 
$$(xf(x))'=f(x)+xf'(x)$$

so let
$$F(x)=xf(x)$$
then 
$$F'(x)>0$$
so
if $x\ge0$,then
$$F(x)>F(0) =0\Longrightarrow xf(x)>0\Longrightarrow f(x)>0$$
if $x\le 0$,then
$$F(x)\le 0\Longrightarrow f(x)>0$$